# Grid is not working in Internet Explorer while working fine in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Grid is not working in Internet Explorer while its working fine in Firefox and Google Chrome. I think there is some mistake some where in java script. only grid top row is displaying while second row is not appending Here is my code

```
function contractor_details(data)
{
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        var contrator_table = document.getElementById('contractor_detail');
        var cname = data[i].contractor;
        var address = data[i].address;
}
    $('#enlistmentData').html('');
    if(data.length==1){
        $('#enlistmentData').html('<input type="hidden" name="contname" id="enlistmentinput" value= "'+data[0].contractor+'" />');
    }else{
    $('#enlistmentData').append('<table border="1" style="width:100%" id="enlistmentData_table"><tr><td></td><td><font size=3>Company Name</font></td><td><font size=3>Address</font></td></tr></table>');
$.each(data,function(k,val){
    $('#enlistmentData_table').append('<tr><td align=left><input type="radio" name="contname" value="'+val.contractor+'"></td><td>'+val.contractor+'</td><td>'+val.address+'</td></tr></table>');
        });
    }
```

}

Comment: Which versions of IE is it not working in? Can make a big difference.

Comment: It's possible that IE is having trouble appending the rows to #enlistmentData_table because it is created just prior to the append. Would be more efficient to add each row in memory and then write the whole thing out to the DOM in one shot.